# Having built a url, how do I retrieve a specific parameter value?

Tags: java, url, servlets

I have a "forgot password" link. Using it sends an email containing a url redirecting you to a change password page. I built the url like this:

```
String baseURL = url.substring(0, url.length() -  
        request.getRequestURI().length()) + request.getContextPath() + 
        "/content/resetPassword.jsp?uuid=";
```

Then a uuid is generated and written to a table. When the user clicks onthe url, they should be able to change the password. But, I need to retrieve the uuid from the url and use it in my search to find the correct password to modify.

I have tried to use `getQueryString` and replace the uuid but it doesn’t seem to work correctly.

How do I get use the random uuid and not everything after the '?'?

Comment: `request.getParameter("uuid");`

Comment: Should make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something, you could use [`ServletRequest.getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) and something like

```
String uuid = request.getParameter("uuid");
```

Per the linked Javadoc, `ServletRequest.getParameter(String)`,

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a `String`, or null if the parameter does not exist.